# Updating textbox based on datagrid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this datagrid view which links to the table `answers` in the database. The user can edit answers to questions in this form, but I'd like for the textbox to be updated as the button moves onto next answer. This is so the user can edit/delete stuff in the textbox and save it.

```
    private void NextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        QuestionsBindingSource.MoveNext();
    }
```

How can I get the textbox to refresh based on selected record in datagridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `BindingSource`, you can get the `Current` object, cast it to it's type, and get a value.

Let's assume you are bound to a DataTable:

```
private void NextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (QuestionsBindingSource != null)
    {
        QuestionsBindingSource.MoveNext();
        if (QuestionsBindingSource.Current != null)
        {
            DataRow row = (DataRow)QuestionBindingSource.Current;
            yourTextBox.Text = row["FieldYouWant"].ToString();
        }
    }   
}
```

What you cast `Current` to and the subsequent value reference are both dependent upon what you are bound to (what `QuestionsBindingSource` is).  Adjust this example accordingly.

Comment: I do use DataTable. I get this error when I press the button `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Quiz.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.`

Comment: As I said, you must change the cast and assignment to match the type you actually have.  In this case, you do _not_ have `DataRow`, you have `DataRowView`.